# label orientation after dxf to shp conversion

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, python-2.7

I'm writing a script with python in QGIS that allows me to convert a dxf file to shp. In the dxf file I have oriented text but after the conversion I lose this information. Is it possible to keep it?
this is my script :

```
import os 
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
import datetime
print datetime.datetime.now().minute
uri="C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/stage_brome/restitution.dxf|layername=entities"
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 'layer', 'ogr')
##For each sublayer, diferent type of geometry, load a layer to map.
subLayers = vlayer.dataProvider().subLayers()
types=["LineString","Point","Polygon"]
for sublayer in subLayers:
    #Extract the geometry type
    geom_type = sublayer.split(':')[-1]
    #Set the path
    url = str(uri)+"|layername=entities|geometrytype="+str(geom_type)
    #Name for sub layer
    dxf_file_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(url))[0]
    layer_name =str(dxf_file_name)+" - "+str(geom_type)
    #Create layer
    sub_vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(url, layer_name, 'ogr')
    #Add layer to map
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(sub_vlayer)
    if geom_type in types:
        #list of string that contains the name of each layer 
        layer_types=[]
        #list of vector layers 
        vlayers_by_type=[]
        #list of providers for each vector layer
        vlayers_providers=[]
        geom_types=[]

        for feature in sub_vlayer.getFeatures():
            #fill the lists (vector layer and it's provider and attributes of each layer)
            if (feature.attributes())[0] not in layer_types:
                name=(feature.attributes())[0]
                layer_types.append(name)
                # create vlayer
                vl=QgsVectorLayer(geom_type, "temporary_points", "memory")
                geom_types.append(geom_type)
                pr = vl.dataProvider()
                # add fields
                fields=[field for field in sub_vlayer.pendingFields()]
                pr.addAttributes(fields)
                # tell the vector layer to fetch changes from the provider
                vl.updateFields()
                vlayers_by_type.append(vl)
                vlayers_providers.append(pr)
                error = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(vl, "C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/stage_brome/output/layers/"+name+"-"+str(geom_type)+".shp", "CP1250", None, "ESRI Shapefile")
#                if error != QgsVectorFileWriter.NoError:
#                    print "failed  "------------------------------------

        for feature in sub_vlayer.getFeatures():
            name=(feature.attributes())[0] 
            if name in layer_types:
                # add features 
                vl=vlayers_by_type[layer_types.index(name)]
                pr=vlayers_providers[layer_types.index(name)]
                pr.addFeatures([feature])
                # update layer's extent when new features have been added
                # because change of extent in provider is not propagated to the layer
                geom_type=geom_types[layer_types.index(name)]
                vl.updateExtents()
                error = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(vl, "C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/stage_brome/output/layers/"+str(name)+"-"+str(geom_type)+".shp", "CP1250", None, "ESRI Shapefile")
                if error != QgsVectorFileWriter.NoError:
                    print "failed  "+str(layer_types[vlayers_by_type.index(vl)])

print datetime.datetime.now().minute
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. The plugin "[AnotherDXF2Shape](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/AnotherDXF2Shape/)" makes that.

[edit]
You must use the appropriate SQL code with OGR.

```
import processing
dxfdat="d:/.../test.dxf"
shpdat="d:/.../dxf2.shp"

opt="-skipfailure  --config DXF_MERGE_BLOCK_GEOMETRIES FALSE --config DXF_INLINE_BLOCKS TRUE  -nlt POINT "
sql= "-sql \"select *, ogr_style from entities where OGR_GEOMETRY LIKE '%POINT%'\""

print processing.runalg('gdalogr:convertformat',dxfdat , 0,opt + sql, shpdat)
```

Then you find the angle in the DBF column `ogr_style` Param `a:<win>`:

```
LABEL(f:"Arial",t:"mytext",p:1,s:0.603g,c:#000000,a:143.25)
```

1) In Plugin "AnotherDXF2Shape" there is a Option: **"Group layer".**
[image]

2) My Code produce a shape with a DBF. In the DBF exist a field "Layer".

```
import processing
dxfdat="d:/test.dxf"
shpdat="d:/point.shp"
savedir="d:/output/layers/"

# Step 1: Create a Shape with POINT's
opt="-skipfailure  --config DXF_MERGE_BLOCK_GEOMETRIES FALSE --config DXF_INLINE_BLOCKS TRUE  -nlt POINT "
sql= "-sql \"select *, ogr_style from entities where OGR_GEOMETRY LIKE '%POINT%'\""

print processing.runalg('gdalogr:convertformat',dxfdat , 0,opt + sql, shpdat)
DBFedit (shpdat) ###!!!!!!!!!!!!!###
# Step 2: Group the Shape by Layer
Layer = QgsVectorLayer(shpdat, "points","ogr") 

fni = Layer.fieldNameIndex('Layer')
unique_values = Layer.dataProvider().uniqueValues(fni)
for AktLayerNam in unique_values:
        Layer = QgsVectorLayer(shpdat, AktLayerNam,"ogr")
        Layer.setSubsetString( "Layer = '" + AktLayerNam + "'" )
        QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(Layer, True) 
        # Step 3:  save Shape by Layer
        QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(Layer, savedir+ AktLayerNam+ ".shp", "CP1250", None, "ESRI Shapefile")
```

**This function edits the point shape.**
Quick&dirty:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import ogr
def DBFedit (shpdat):
    def trennArtDaten(ArtDaten):
        #BRUSH(fc:#dcdcdc)
        #LABEL(f:"Arial",t:"{\fArial|b1|i0|c0|p34;VZOG}",s:3.5g,p:8,c:#ff7f7f)
        sDaten = ""
        sArt = ""
        inDaten = False
        for c in ArtDaten[:-1]:
            if c == '(' and not inDaten:
                inDaten = True
                c = ''
            if inDaten:
                sDaten = sDaten + c
            else:
                sArt = sArt + c
        return sArt, sDaten

    def csvSplit(csvZeile, trenn=',', tKenn='"', tKennDel = True):
        inString = False
        mask = ""
        s = ''
        sb = False
        for c in csvZeile: 

            if c == tKenn and not sb:
                inString = not inString
            if c == trenn and inString  and not sb:
                if mask == "":
                    mask = "$$"
                    while mask in csvZeile:
                        mask = mask + '$'
                s=s+mask
            else:
                if not (tKennDel and (not sb) and c == tKenn): 
                    s=s+c
            if c == "\\":
                sb = True
            else:
                sb = False

        arr = s.split(trenn)
        if mask != "":
            for i in range(0,len(arr)):
                arr[i] = arr[i].replace(mask,trenn)

        return arr

    source = ogr.Open(shpdat, update=True)
    if source is None:
        print('ogr: can not open: ' + shpdat)
        return

    layer = source.GetLayer()
    laydef = layer.GetLayerDefn()

    Found = False
    for i in range(laydef.GetFieldCount()):
        if laydef.GetFieldDefn(i).GetName() == 'ogr_style':
            Found = True

    if not Found:
        print("missing field 'ogr_style': " + shpdat)
        return
    # add a new field for angle
    layer.CreateField(ogr.FieldDefn('angle', ogr.OFTReal))    

    feature = layer.GetNextFeature()
    while feature:
            att=feature.GetField('ogr_style') 
            if att is None:
                print("missing field 'ogr_style' in: "  + shpdat)
            else:
                sArt,sDaten = trennArtDaten(att)
                params = csvSplit (sDaten)
                for param in params:
                    arr=csvSplit(param,":")
                    if len(arr) == 2:
                        f = arr[0]
                        w = arr[1]
                        if f == "a":
                            dWin = float(w)
                            if dWin >=360:
                                dWin = dWin - 360                             
                            feature.SetField('angle', dWin)
                    else:
                        print ("incomplete field 'ogr_style': " + param)

            layer.SetFeature(feature)
            feature = layer.GetNextFeature()
    source.Destroy()
```

Comment: I'm writing my own script because of some other specific needs

Comment: Then please show what you have tried - the relevant code.

Comment: I edit my answer.

Comment: is it possible to combine this with my code ?

Comment: I do not think so. My way is different (processing-modul).
What should your code do, what AnotherDXF2Shape can not do?

Comment: First, in my dxf file i have many layers so i want to keep the same structure for example i can have 10 layers with type point so they should not be merged in one shp fil. Second i have hundreds of files so i should  automate the process

Comment: is it possible to do that with your code? if yes could u help me finding some tutorials?

Comment: 1) My code is complete for convert all points (label) as one DXF. Works these code for you? 2) Have you test the Plugin "AnotherDXF2Shape"? It works for  many DXF with one click and group it by layers.

Comment: your code and the plugin groups the entities according to their geometry but i want to group by type of layer wich is stored in field "Layer" in my code it's "(feature.attributes())[0]"

Comment: I've extended the code by a grouping by layer.

Comment: ... and save as shapefile

Comment: Thank u it's working ! one last question how can I get the angle ? i don't know how to acess the ogr_style field.

Comment: I do not understand your question. You found the column "ogr_style" and do not know how to isolate the angle?
What do you want to do with the angle?

Comment: yes i want to isolate the angle so that i can choose that column when i want to set the label orientation.

Comment: **That's all things that "AnotherDXF2Shape" do!! ** You must edit the DBF for a new column. The problem is complex. I'll see. But it will take a moment.

Comment: I adapted my code.